# Using public variables/members that call custom getters/setters

Tags: java, getter-setter

I am testing myself by attempting to recreate "String" inside of a custom class within Java. That means including variables to hold the actual text, and the length; as examples.

It isn't that I am having a problem, but more of an idea I am uncertain of whether it exists or not.

I use private accessors on all the members that should be accessed through a setter rather than directly. I am just curious about whether you can have a public member use a getter/setter whenever it is accessed?

So if it is being modified through "string_name = "sample string""; it would use the setter. If it is being read through "another_string = string_name"; it would use the getter.

Is there such a thing? I would like to learn more about this.

Comment: Java does not support magic accessors. Lots of languages do, but in Java getters and setters are explicit.

Comment: Ah, that's a shame. I remember reading about it in another language a year or so ago, thought it was a pretty good thing to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there such a thing?

Unfortunately not in Java, other languages do offer that type of functionality e.g. C#, JavaScript, Kotlin et al.

In Java, you'll explicitly have to invoke the appropriate getter and/or setter.

Comment: Might be worth to add Kotlin to that list — it's a JVM language after all.

Comment: @ohlec I guess that's why I added "et al" as there are a good number of languages that offer this functionality. I think Ruby does as well if I am not mistaken. but sure thing, I'll add that if it helps.

Comment: Oh well, it isn't really a game changer. As using a setter or a getter will still accomplish the same things. I just wanted to make it as similar as possible.